# Freeze on JFrame while other is Open

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have an application say two major GUIs (`College-JFrame` and `Department-JFrame`). There is `JButton` - `ManageDepartmentButton` - that opens the `Department-JFrame`.

I want `College-JFrame` GUI to freeze or non-clickable when ever `Department-JFrame` is open.

And after `Department-JFrame` is closed I want to restore / un-freeze the `College-JFrame`.

Is there a way to do this? How? Or any work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `College-JFrame` as the main `JFrame`, but make `Department-JFrame` as modal `JDialog`.

See:

- [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)
- [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)
- [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/597657)

Comment: And how to Open One `JDialog` from another `JDialog`? Like if I want to open `Faculty-JDialog` from `Department-JDialog` ?